# Can I define a parameter by using mappings in CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

This is the important part of my template:

```
Parameters:

  EnvType:
    Description: Environment type.
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - prod
      - test

Mappings:
  EnvDomain:
    Primary:
      prod: "prodexample.com"
      test: "testexample.com"
```

The question I have is can I add a parameter (under "Parameters:" of course) that has a value defined by Mappings? It would look something like this:

```
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Default: !FindInMap ["EnvDomain", "Primary", "${EnvType}"
```

I'm not sure how to !Sub the EnvType in there, can !join be used or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question I have is can I add a parameter (under "Parameters:" of course) that has a value defined by Mappings?

Sadly, you can't do this. Such functionality is **not supported**.

Answer (score 0):

From a semantic point of view i recommend the following:

- Parameters are the variable input
- Mappings are the static constants needed throughout the template

Use a combination of parameters and mappings inside the resource section, e.g.

```yaml
!Sub
    - vpc-${myParam}-${myMapping}
    - myParam: !Ref Parameter1
      myMapping: !FindInMap [x, y, z]
```